# Host does not exist in Putty Windows 7

Tags: svn, ssh, putty

I am using IntelliJ and it comes with SVN support by default. In IntelliJ I am using host lets say: svn+ssh://hostname.com and I can checkout files from this place with no problems. IntelliJ asks for a private key which I provide, then my username and my password and it all works fine..

Now when I use PuTTY I provide the same host name ( svn+ssh://hostname.com ) and I provide the same private key in Connection\SSH\Auth part of the software. Then I click "Open" but all I get is:

[image]

What can it be that I am doing wrong in a such simple process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

First, try just connecting to "hostname.com" - remove the ssh:// etc.

If that fails, try using the IP address for your host rather than the name.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue (but Windows 10), the solution was simply to run the following command in `cmd` :

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Just this.